# Editable grid in VB6

Tags: vb6, grid

I'm trying to edit a grid ( not flexgrid) in VB6 (not .NET) , I don't know why but first row is allowed to edit but not the second one and I can't find the property to change it, not 'lock' not 'allowupdate'

Additional Information:
Ok The problem was that I had a condition in the query

```
IIf ( field1 is null, 0 , field1) as field
```

How to solve this? I don't know yet but it works if I write

```
field1 as field
```

Thank you ,

Comment: Are you using a datagrid? And are you connecting it to a database or something similar? question not very clear.

Comment: There are lots of grid controls available in VB6. What control are you using: the built-in DataGrid from msdatgrd.ocx, the ComponentOne TrueGrid, something else? What properties have you set?

Comment: Having seen the additional info in the edit. It looks as if you have bound one column in your grid to an expression in a Sql query? In that case, yes, that column will be read-only. If you bind it to direct to a column in the database, it will be read-write.